# How can I mock and add a target when using a `patch` as a context manager?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a really simple module like this:

```
def do(url):
    try:
        check(url)
        foo(url)
    except:
        bar(url)

def check(url):
    # some other stuff
    if ' ' in url:
        raise Exception('oops')
```

To unit test `do` I need to mock `check`, which would otherwise have some side effects.

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from main import do

def test_check_process():
    with patch('main.check') as method:
        do('http://something')
        assert method.call_count == 1
```

My problem is that I also need the (mocked) `check` function to sometimes throw an exception. The `patch` function has the ability to provide a target via the `new` keyword, but when I change to patch the target function I get an error like `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'call_count'`.

```
def mock_checker(url):
    if ' ' in url:
        raise Exception('oops')

def test_check_process():
    with patch('main.check', new=mock_checker) as method:
        do('http://something')
        assert method.call_count == 1
```

It seems like, when providing the `new` parameter, the `patch` context manager isn't a regular patch object and I can't spy on it at all.

How should I patch a function using the `unittest` module?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) section of docs

Comment: Thanks @MauroBaraldi - I believe I'm following the documentation correctly. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

You defined a new `mock_checker` function, it's not mock object. The [call_count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_count) property only exists on `unittest.mock.Mock`. We can use [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) to raise an exception for the mock object.

E.g.

`main.py`:

```py
def do(url):
    try:
        check(url)
        foo(url)
    except:
        bar(url)


def check(url):
    if ' ' in url:
        raise Exception('oops')


def foo(url):
    pass


def bar(url):
    pass
```

`test_main.py`:

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
from main import do


def test_check_process():
    with patch('main.check', side_effect=Exception('oops')) as mock_check:
        print(mock_check)
        do('http://something')

        assert mock_check.call_count == 1


def test_check_process_2():
    mock_checker = MagicMock(side_effect=Exception('oops'))
    with patch('main.check', new=mock_checker) as mock_check:
        print(mock_check)
        do('http://something')
        assert mock_check.call_count == 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_check_process()
    test_check_process_2()
```

The execution result:

```
<MagicMock name='check' id='4535123472'>
<MagicMock id='4535121168'>
```

Assert success